# Facebook Page Review From an External Website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any that I can allow a Facebook page customers to review the page from the website after they login to the website using Facebook?

I have read the Facebook API documentation but the reviews API Documentation shows only how to retrieve the reviews to be shown in the website.

Comment: No, there is no way to create reviews, other than via the official Facebook UI.